# $15a+6b+4c+8d=0$ implies $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ has a positive root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, cubics

Let $a,b,c,d$ be real numbers such that $15a+6b+4c+8d=0$. Show that $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ has a positive root. ([Komal](http://www.komal.hu/verseny/1998-03/mat.e.shtml), Problem N. 170.)

I want to try to use the intermediate value theorem, showing that $f(s)<0$ and $f(t)>0$ for some $s,t>0$, since this will imply that $f(u)=0$ for some $u>0$. But the numbers $15,6,4,8$ do not yield easily to plugging in appropriate values of $x$.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Descartes' Rule of Signs which states that

*An equation f(x) = 0 cannot have more positive roots than there are changes of sign in f (x), and cannot have more negative roots than there are changes of sign in f (— x)*.

Since $15a+6b+4c+8d=0$ this implies that there is atleast one negative number and one positive number in the set ${a,b,c,d}$. This implies that the original cubic will have atleast one change in sign which implies that it can have one positive root.

Comment: Doesn't that mean it can have *up to* one positive root, but it's not guaranteed? The question is asking how 15a+6b+4c+8d guarantees that the other equation has a positive root.